# Trying to use vertical-align middle on absolute positioned elelement

Tags: css, css-position, vertical-alignment

I am having issues with my next and previous arrows on my slider. The slider is built to shrink and expand with the window. Everything looks great in all browsers except for safari. The buttons are at the top of the slider instead of the middle.

I've tried everything I can think of to fix this. Any ideas?

Here is the site http://upperdeck.dev.warp9inc.com

Here is the code for the buttons.

```
.slideshow-wrapper .backward {
    position:absolute;
    left: 10px;
    margin-top:10%;
    background:url(../../images/infortis/super-slideshow/slideshow-arrows.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

.slideshow-wrapper .forward {
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    margin-top:10%;
    background:url(../../images/infortis/super-slideshow/slideshow-arrows.png) -50px 0 no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is absolutely positioned elements are block-level elements without any exception - and `vertical-align` only applies to elements in the inline-formatting context and table-cells

Comment: Ok thanks. Thats what I thought. I originally used 'margin-top:10%' which works great on all browsers except for safari. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use `top` instead of `margin-top`? Also after inspecting your `.slideshow-wrapper` in chrome it seems it doesn't spread on all of the content's slider, I think you need to fix this, try `min-height: 450px;`

Comment: Thanks! However, I cannot set a 'min-height' b/c the content below it will stay fixed. I tried 'top' as well :) The slider images are meant to resize when the browser is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For absolutely positioned elements, you can center them like this

```
top: 50%;
margin-top: -25px
```

That also works for horizontally centering absolutely positioned items, and will work even if the parent changes size dynamically.

You set top and/or left to 50%, and then margin-top/margin-left to negative 1/2 the width of the item you're trying to center. So, your CSS would look like this:

```
/* Make sure .slideshow-wrapper has position: relative; */  
.slideshow-wrapper .backward {
        position:absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -25px;
        background:url(../../images/infortis/super-slideshow/slideshow-arrows.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
    }

    .slideshow-wrapper .forward {
        position:absolute;
        right:10px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -25px;
        background:url(../../images/infortis/super-slideshow/slideshow-arrows.png) -50px 0 no-repeat;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
    }
```

What that's doing is telling the div to be absolutely positioned at 50% of the parent, but since it uses the top or left edge, and not the middle of your element, it won't be quite centered. Thus, you need to offset the position to the left or top by half the width or height of your element so that the middle of your element will fall at 50% of it's parent.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please have a look at this in Safari. Still seems like it doesn't want to stay centered http://upperdeck.dev.warp9inc.com

Comment: I don't have access to Safari right now, so I can't check it. However, it looks like the problem you're having is because there's no height explicitly set on .slideshow-wrapper. Without using Javascript, I'm not sure if there is a reliable way to vertically center a div who's parent doesn't have an explicit height

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll look into that and see what I can do and update ya :)